# How to download data from Dash-Heroku app linked to AWS Postgres RDS into a computer?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, amazon-web-services, heroku

I'm kind of new to web applications, so here is my problem.

I developed an interactive dashboard with Plotly's Dash that connects to an RDS postgres instance of AWS via psycopg2 (Before that, it was connected to a local instance of psql, and it works the same).

The database hosts data from Mexico's electricity market and is around 9 GB big.
In the dashboard I gave the opportunity to download information from the database (selecting time interval and other things which are just extra factors inside the WHERE clause).

I was able to use the command `cursor.copy_expert(SQL-QUERY, outfile-path)` to download the file to a specified folder when the python code was launched locally in my computer.

I decided to host my app in Heroku, and the database in AWS. Everything works perfectly, except data download to computer, it doesn't work at all.

The thing is, How can I use that command (Or is there other I should use?) in order to make a SQL query to the database and download the results as a CSV to the computer accesing the heroku page?

Information downloaded range from less than 1 MB to 1 GB.

I have not been able to find out a way to solve this, Please help.

Thanks!

Comment: Your `cursor.copy()` command would create a file _on the machine where you're running it_, not your local computer.

Comment: But the problem is that the code is running on Heroku, not on a local computer, so I cannot `cursor.copy()` because you need to specify a path to the destination file, but as it's running on Heroku I don't know what path to write or how to do it. You are accesing the webpage and the webpage is connected to the RDS instance. So I want to download the file like a normal downloadable csv web file. How should I do it?

Comment: That's what I said in my comment. Please red the marked duplicate for a better solution.